# Unable to get Chrome inspector to link to SCSS source map file generated from Web Essentials

Tags: css, iis, visual-studio-2013, sass, web-essentials

I am trying to get Chrome's developer tools to recognize and use my scss map file so I can more easily debug my scss styles. It seems like Chrome, for some reason, is not picking up on the styles.css.map file and so it is **only** showing me the generated css styles in the inspector and not exposing the scss files.

**tools I'm using:**

- visual studio 2013
- Web essentials
- IIS
- chrome

**current configurations:**

- web essentials sass compilation is configured to generate css and css.map files and seems to be working correctly. The css and map files are generated in the same directory as the scss file and updated on save.
  [view my web essentials settings here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMMrD.png)
- chrome settings are set to enable css source maps and to auto-reload generated source maps
  [view chrome settings here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlnpG.png)

**file structure**

I've set up a very simple file structure to try to narrow down the issue and eliminate any extra complications that my main application could introduce:

```
/index.html
/styles.css
/styles.scss
/styles.css.map
```

**UPDATE 1:**

I manipulated the url to see if I could go right to the files and it looks like the styles.css.map file is available but the styles.scss file is not available. so I guess VS or IIS are not serving those files. I'm guessing this is because of some configuration that needs made in IIS or VS?

**UPDATE 2:**

I found out that the mime type needs to be set up in visual studio or IIS in order for it to recognize the scss file type. I set that up in my web.config and now it is completely working in FireFox but is still not working in Chrome for some reason. But I CAN access all the .map and .scss files if I go to them directly by url. Now I need to figure out why this isnt working in chrome.

Comment: I would look at seeing if the sourcemaps work in another browser like firefox or something to see if they work there. If they do, then it's a Chrome issue, if they don't then there is something wrong with your build configuration. I say this because it looks like you may have properly setup Chrome, which makes it look like its a problem with the build.

Comment: Thanks, I tried in firefox and it is displaying styles.scss in the inspector so it LOOKS like its working. but when I click on the link to view the actual file, it just brings up the code for a 404 error page. so I guess somehow the file is not available. I'm wondering if IIS is not serving the source files since they're not actually referenced in the project? I'm not really strong with visual studio and IIS so any input in that area is greatly appreciated

Comment: Honestly man, if you are just getting into using preprocessors/build tools, there really is enough to learn/deal with, such that you probably don't need your editor getting in the way, too. I would recommend picking up something much more light weight -- like Atom or Sublime Text. From there, you may want to look into using gulp for simple builds, and then eventually move your way on up to something like Webpack. 

In all honesty, build tools have gotten so good that I would wager to say that most professionals do NOT use heavy IDEs like Visual Studio or WebStorm.

Comment: @Pytth I am on a much larger project with a Microsoft development team so I don't have that option.

Comment: Ahh. Well, for frontend development, I dont get why you couldn't come up with your own simple build file for handling SASS and source maps. Here is an example of my gulp task that handles my sass and my source maps: (putting it in an answer for the formatted code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally figured out the issue! in Tools > Options > Web Essentials > SASS, I set "Use Ruby Runtime" to True and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of my gulp file. Even if you are on a big team, for small things like sourcemaps and sass, I am having a hard time understanding why you wouldn't be able to step outside of your IDE to do this stuff.

```
//'required' in everything above.
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    gulp.src('server/src/styles/index.scss')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(concat('styles.css'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./server/tmp'));
});
```

And to run the task, from my terminal, I can just run `gulp sass`. Of course, my FULL build has other things, too, like browser-sync autoprefixer, gulp watch, etc. All very nice things that are not very difficult to setup.

Comment: using a different editor is not an option. I need to be able to perform/debug backend tasks as well. thanks though

Comment: You can use the same editor with gulp. At my last job, we all used WebStorm but still had separate builds outside of the IDE itself.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have figured this out but to be specific - add the following to the web.config.

```
<staticContent>
 ...
 <mimeMap fileExtension=".scss" mimeType="text/css" />
 ...
</staticContent>
```